Understanding of Salaf & Fuqaha on Treaty of Hudaibiyyah
Many people justify making agreements using the treaty of Hudaibiyyah that Ruler can deport a Muslim to their enemy who imprisons them and even tortures them.

Example: Uyghur being detained and deported to China from certain Muslim countries. This being justified by people claiming in treaty of Hudaibiyyah Prophet sent returned certain Sahabah who escaped Makkah due to persecution after this treaty.

But How did Fuqaha understand the matter related to the Treaty of Hudaibiyyah and how did they derive whether such agreements are valid or not for future generations to come?
